# IOS sharing framework for twitter, facebook, flicr, tumblr

Tags: iphone, sharing

I need to share UIImage from my IOS application to Facebook, Twitter, Flicr, Picassa (if possible), Tumblr.

Is there any library that can help me with this task?
Or should i download SDK for every one social network?

Please, help me, and
thank you for the answers:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) is an option as it covers some of the services you require.

Comment: I believe that link is to the "old" ShareKit that is no longer supported and has some issues. You should try ShareKit 2.0 (https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the Socialize SDK which handles sharing and user management as well: http://www.getsocialize.com

Answer (score 3):

For Facebook and Twitter, you can use the simple way bellow. The UI will look like Twitter on iOS 5 and Facebook on iOS 6: https://github.com/lephukhanhhuy/easyshare-ios4.3.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Great share API http://www.addthis.com/