# uploading photos/videos on facebook app running on android or ios?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

Im going to write a facebook app which will be embedded on the site fanpage.

The main aim is to collect some information and get user's picture or video. User will be able to choose the one from the "filesystem" -> on PC browser this is regular upload form.

The question is -> should I expect any problems with uploading photos/videos from mobile devices -> android, iOS, blackBerry ?

Answer (score 0):

> "should I expect any problems with uploading photos/videos from mobile devices -> android, iOS, blackBerry ?"

**No**.

But 1 thing you should know that the user wont be able to `post photos/videos to the friends` wall (if that's in your requirement); yet there's a workaround that the user can tag his/her friends in the photo/video.

> Some links that *might* be useful to you-

**Videos**

[Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12470730/1343690)
[iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355846/iphone-facebook-video-upload)

[API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/)

**Photos**

[Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109283/android-upload-photo-to-facebook-with-facebook-android-sdk) [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984976/how-to-post-a-photo-ios-facebook-sdk-3-1/12984978#12984978)

[API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)