# How to share images on tumblr?

Tags: iphone, ios6, tumblr

I have an application in which I need to share images on tumblr and access the image from tumblr.

Is there any API by which we can get this thing?

Answer (score 0):

May below links works:

http://getsharekit.com/tutorial/tumblr

[IOS sharing framework for twitter, facebook, flicr, tumblr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825548/ios-sharing-framework-for-twitter-facebook-flicr-tumblr)

[Image sharing via Tumblr and Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171113/image-sharing-via-tumblr-and-path)